# Seen the full text with ScrollView

Tags: android

I want to see all the text in the layout using the Scroll to down. But I can see only the part of all text and it can not be moved with **ScrollView**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t1"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
            android:gravity="right" android:autoText="false" android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_below="@+id/textView" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="right" android:textStyle="bold" android:autoText="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t3"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="right" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
            android:autoText="true"/>
```

Comment: u cannot see any view outside a scrollview if the scroll view has occupied ur full screen that is (fill_parent). Its like u cannot see anything beyond the event horizon of a black hole..Put all the views(within a single parent layout) inside a scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

nfortunately, the way you set up your layout is wrong. You directly closed the ScrollView, so the other layout elements are set below it, not inside.
Additionally, a ScollView can only have one child element.

So please update your layout to this:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t1"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
            android:gravity="right" android:autoText="false" android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_below="@+id/textView" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="right" android:textStyle="bold" android:autoText="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t3"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
            android:autoText="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>                
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: A small correction your container is a RelativeLayout and you are using  android:orientation="vertical" does this work better change it to LinearLayout

Comment: @sunilsunny Thanks, that was a stupid copy/paste error. I will correct it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You closed scrollview so that its happen.
 put your code inside scrollview

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

   your code
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

**it's because your layout is wrong**. scrollView must enclose a single child only.
change your layout to something like this

```
<RelativeLayout>   
      <scrollView>
          <RelativeLayout>
                 <TextView>.. etc
          </RelativeLayout>
      </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```